# As I try compiling my c code it keeps notifying me that " line 13:error:identifier expected ".my programming involves storing string of arrays

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct names

{
char name1[49];

char name2[48];

char name3[49];

};

stud1,stud2,stud3;

int main()

{

char names;

printf("enter first name of the first student\n");

 scanf("%s",&struct names.name1.stud1);

printf("enter second  name of the first student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name2.stud1);

printf("enter third  name of the first student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name3.stud1);

printf("enter first name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name1.stud2);

printf("enter second  name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name2.stud2);

printf("enter third  name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name3.stud2);

printf("enter first name of the third  student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name1.stud3);

printf("enter second  name of the third student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name2.stud3);

printf("enter third  name of the third student\n");

scanf("%s",&struct names.name3.stud3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after the closing braces of your `struct` definition.

Comment: There's more wrong than just that.  The use of `struct names` in the `scanf` argument lists is incorrect.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, but not on line 13 :-)

Comment: I don't understand why do most of the people post code without correct indent. It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct definition looks okay, but this:

```
stud1,stud2,stud3;
```

will declare three integer variables. It won't compile under newer standards such as C99. You want three variable of type `struct names` here:

```
struct names stud1, stud2, stud3;
```

When you use the variables:

```
scanf("%s",&struct names.name1.stud1);
```

you don't use `struct names`, which is the type of the variable `stud1`. It is used only when you declate the variable so the compiler knows what type it is. After that, use its name. Also, the struct variable bname goes first, the field name next. And the fiels `name1` is a char array, so you shouldn't take its address. Finally, it is a good idea to signal `scanf` not to overflow the array. So:

```
scanf("%48s", &stud1.name1);
```

Please read the chapter on types and variables in your C primer again.

**Addendum**: It is okay to define the struct and variables in one go, as others have suggested:

```
struct names {
    char name1[49];
    char name2[48];
    char name3[49];
} stud1, stud2, stud3;
```

I find such compound definitions more confusing than useful. I recommend that as a beginner, you should stick to the separation of struct and variable definition.

You can get this definition be removing the seimcolon after the struct body in your code, but it will not fix the systax where you use the structs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

#include

```
struct names

{
char name1[49];

char name2[48];

char name3[49];

}stud1,stud2,stud3;

int main()

{
printf("enter first name of the first student\n");

 scanf("%s",&stud1.name1);

printf("enter second  name of the first student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud1.name2);

printf("enter third  name of the first student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud1.name3);

printf("enter first name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud1.name1);

printf("enter second  name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud2.name2);

printf("enter third  name of the second  student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud2.name3);

printf("enter first name of the third  student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud3.name1);

printf("enter second  name of the third student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud3.name2);

printf("enter third  name of the third student\n");

scanf("%s",&stud3.name3);

return 0;
}
```